# Issue calling $el with forEach() function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, web

I am unable to use the element value inside the forEach() funtion

```
var filtered = rawData.map(function(x){
        return {
          state       : x.state,
          active      : x.active,
          deaths      : x.deaths,
          recovered   : x.recovered
        };
})
```

Using the above in the following loop :

```
for(i=1; i<=filtered.length; i++){
        let tr = document.createElement("tr");
        tr.setAttribute("align","center");    
        document.querySelector('tbody').appendChild(tr);

        ndata = ['state', 'active', 'deaths', 'recovered']
        ndata.forEach((el, k) => {
          let td$k = document.createElement('td');
          td$k.innerText = filtered[i].$el;        // <-- ERROR //
          tr.appendChild(td$k);
        });
```

The browser is throwing back this error :
app.js:201 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$el' of undefined

Comment: That's because you don't have $el anywhere. Use console log here to see what's inside filtered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can access an object's properties by using the dot notation or the bracket notation like:

```
object.property
object['property']
```

But here `el` is a not a property on object `filtered[i]`. It is the key value as a string, so we need to use the bracket notation like:

```
td$k.innerText = filtered[i][el];
```

For more info check docs on [Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

Comment: Holy Guacamole, it worked : 
td$k.innerText = filtered[i][el]; <-- this is the change that worked

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something, but this worked for me to call the value dynamically... I also had to start the loop at i=0 (instead of i=1 above).

```js
ndata = ['state', 'active', 'deaths', 'recovered']
            ndata.forEach((el, k) => {
                let td$k = document.createElement('td');
                td$k.innerText = filtered[i][el];       
                tr.appendChild(td$k);
            });
```